# SQL order by highest date values from other tables

Tags: oracle

I have this tables:

**QUESTION**

```
ID  |  Name      | date_time
1    question1      a date
2    question2      a date
3    question3      a date
```

**ANSWER**

```
ID  |  question_id | date_time
1      1             a date
2      1             a date
3      2             a date
```

**COMMENT**

```
ID  |  question_id | answer_id | date_time
1      NULL            1           a date
2      1               NULL        a date
3      2               NULL        a date
```

A question can have multiple answers AND comments

A answer belongs to a single question

And a comment belongs to a question OR answer! Not both on the same time.

I need to order the questions with the most recent 'activity', the latest date from a question, an answer or a reaction.

I already added up the tables and managed to order by dates

```
SELECT q.*, a.last_date_answer, r.last_date_reaction
FROM QUESTION q LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT question_id, MAX(date_time) AS last_date_answer
       FROM ANSWER a
       GROUP BY question_id) a
ON q.id = a.question_id LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT question_id, MAX(date_time) AS last_date_reaction
       FROM REACTION r
       GROUP BY question_id) r
ON q.id = r.question_id
ORDER BY date_time DESC,
     CASE WHEN last_date_answer IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
     CASE WHEN last_date_reaction IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

This gives the following dummy output:

```
date_time | - | last_date_answer | last_date_reaction
03-MAY-14   5   03-MAY-13          03-MAY-12
03-MAY-13   4   03-MAY-14          03-MAY-15
03-MAY-10   3   03-MAY-12          03-MAY-12
```

But I need the highest know date, which belongs by a single question (highest question, answer OR reaction date within a question). Can't figure it out.. I hope I was a bit clear!

Comment: Create http://sqlfiddle.com with input data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *[GREATEST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm)* function in select statement to get the max date from these joined tables, then you can sort them by that column.
Your query should be looks like this :

```
SELECT q.*, a.last_date_answer, r.last_date_reaction,
GREATEST(date_time, 
    NVL(a.last_date_answer,TO_DATE('01/01/0001','DD/MM/YYYY')),
    NVL(r.last_date_reaction,TO_DATE('01/01/0001','DD/MM/YYYY'))
) X
FROM QUESTION q LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT question_id, MAX(date_time) AS last_date_answer
       FROM ANSWER a
       GROUP BY question_id) a
ON q.id = a.question_id LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT question_id, MAX(date_time) AS last_date_reaction
       FROM REACTION r
       GROUP BY question_id) r
ON q.id = r.question_id
ORDER BY X DESC
```